# How to understand caffe reshape parameter

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I can understand the first 3 examples but not the last one.
If it was originally `2 x 8(only two dimension)`, then, how does `dim: -1  dim: 0  dim:  2` make it `2 x 2 x 4`?  It says only `-1` and `0` has special meaning so the last parameter `2` here should mean the size of the dimension. Isn't it a typo of `dim: -1  dim: 0  dim:  4` ?

```
  // If "input" is 2D with shape 2 x 8, then the following reshape_param
  // specifications are all equivalent, producing a 3D blob "output" with shape
  // 2 x 2 x 4:
  //
  //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  2  dim: 2  dim:  4 } }
  //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  0  dim: 2  dim:  4 } }
  //   reshape_param { shape { dim:  0  dim: 2  dim: -1 } }
  //   reshape_param { shape { dim: -1  dim: 0  dim:  2 } }
```

Comment: What version of Caffe are you looking at? looking at recent version caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto I see the last example has dim:4 as you expect

Comment: Agree with @Shai. It should be `dim: -1  dim: 0  dim:  4` according to the version of caffe https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was using py-caffe (faster-rcnn). it is March 6th, 2016 version and it appears to have typo there.